# Aws Lambda - Using java11 and node.js together

Tags: java, node.js, aws-lambda

I have an AWS java 11 lambda that uses node.js as well - meaning a java application that needs to run something on node.js as well.
Is there a way to deploy a lambda with 2 runtimes (java11 and node.jsX)?

I know I can add a layer to the lambda with the relevant node.js binaries and use it, but it's not ideal.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Have you thought about containerizing your app and then pushing it to Lambda? fyi, Lambda now supports Container images [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html)

Comment: yes, but I thought it would be easier as a layer.

Comment: That would be a much cleaner solution imo

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Lambda layer approach would be very easy to work with. I would use one of the [Lambda base container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-images.html) and then add any additional binaries you require.